# Is there a way to see if my bot is offline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

Is there a way to see if my Discord bot is offline with a pyhton script? I'm trying to make a script that detects if my bot goes offline and it will run it in my other server if my host has a maintenance.
Is there any way to detect this?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow the flask approach using [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com/) to ping your web app every so often but this is limited to alerts if downtime is more than 5 minutes.

You could look at getting a reliable host that doesn't go down as often or looking at getting a VPS with a host with a high uptime SLA. You can look at https://uptime.is/ for seeing how long downtime is acceptable for a host.

If you know how to create good API servers, create a socket.io server, connect to it using your bot. Then listen for the disconnect event on the server then you know when your bot goes down/restarts.